# How to know the URL of the page that is loading my script?

Tags: php

`a.com` is my server where a PHP script is located, called `makejs.php`. The script generates javascript (go figure).

On `b.com` (which I don't control) there is HTML that says `<script src="a.com/makejs.php"></script>`.

When the request comes for `makejs.php` on `a.com`, how can i get the full URL of the page from `b.com` that initiated the request?

Comment: How is `b.com` loading the script? Is it linking to it, using `file_get_contents`, `cURL`?

Comment: I'm don't see where server `a` has anything to do with your problem. You're trying to have the `b` web server send a request to itself for a file. Does it have permissions to access that file?

Comment: b.com is loading it as a script <script src="a.com/script.php"></script>

Comment: Why do you want `b` to get to the file by sending a request to itself? The server `b` will have great range of permissions just trying to access the file in the PHP script itself....or do you not have access to `b` and you're trying to hack it by modifying the script on `a`?

Comment: I only have access to a.com. No I am not hacking anything.

Comment: OK, but the script from `a` is being executed in `b`, right? So write the script as if you were on `b`. That is, don't get a local file with `file_get_contents`, just open it and read it.

Comment: How has this anything to do why `file_get_contents`? I just want to get the full URL but `$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";` is not working probably because a.com and b.com are different domains?

Comment: Is that `<script>` tag loading JavaScript i.e. is `script.php` outputting JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, but I want to avoid a javascript solution if possible.

Comment: Oh, `b.com` isn't loading the script from `a.com` at all. The client is. But you want the js from `a.com` to know where the page that loaded it was served from, right?

Comment: YES! EXACTLY THIS! Sorry if I was confusing.

Comment: Is my edit of your question correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best you can do in `a.com/makejs.php` is look at `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. Here's more info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

The variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` shows the page that had a link to the currently-requested resource. Give it a try.

Notice that the documentation says that the value of the variable comes from the client. It is sometimes not set, and in most clients it can be manipulated. Don't trust it if this is a critical application.

Comment: just dont assume HTTP_REFERER is going to exist  or  is correct.

Comment: I tried this solution at first. But HTTP_REFERER was empty. So I thought it does not work in this situation. But I guess it's because of my browser settings. Is this or is a javascript solution more reliable? I know both could be fake, so when I say reliable I mean what is more often not empty?

Comment: If HTTP_REFERER doesn't work for you, you're out of luck as far as `a.com` knowing the source of HTML that linked to `a.com`. What exactly are you trying to do and why? Maybe there's another way to get there.

Comment: It's a little bit more complex but simply said: User goes to b.com and is redirected to a.com.
I would have prefered if I would instantly get the referer. But the other way I was thinking of:
The script adds the current url from b.com with javascript to the redirect url (which redirects to a.com) and sends it as a get variable.

Comment: To do that, you'd have to have control of the script that comes from `b.com`, but you don't.

Comment: It loads some JavaScript from a.com so I can bascially add anything I want to b.com.

Comment: OK, maybe you could have the first script from `a.com` check the window.location.href in javascript, then send another request to `a.com` via ajax and include the URL there.

Comment: I will use this `var url = window.location.href;` in the `makejs.php` and add the url to the javascript redirect so I get the url from b.com as a $_GET variable in a.com

Comment: I think that will work. If it does, please update this post so we can see how you did it.